# API para consulta código de barras

Tags: laravel, web-service, aplicação-web, api

Estou há negociar com uma empresa um *software* a ser desenvolvido, dentre as necessidades surgiu o cadastro do produto de forma rápida sem precisar de muitas entradas do usuário. Diante disso tive a ideia de talvez obter as informações básicas do produtos através de alguma *API* e etc. Este *software* seria para o controle de pedido internos na empresa, uma loja do varejo.

**Alguém conhece alguma *API* tanto gratuita como paga em que se possa consultar tais informações?**

Outra ideia que tive seria pela importação do XML da nota fiscal, porém para o controle interno o código de barras seria mais interessante!

Fico a disposição sobre novas ideias.

Comment: [Api Cosmos, da BlueSoft](http://cosmos.bluesoft.com.br/api)

Comment: Obrigado! Conforme verifiquei acho que ira atender!